# Incorrect behavior of the [ModuleInitializer]?

Tags: c#, clr, clr-module-initializer

I try to use [ModuleInitializer] in .net5 code. My test assembly

```
namespace TestAssembly
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [ModuleInitializer]
        public static void Init()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ModuleInitializer");
        }
    }
}
```

I need the Init() method to be called on the assembly loading. Loading code

```
byte[] rawAssembly = LoadFile("TestAssembly.dll");
Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
```

But the initializer isn't called on loading. Also I tried

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("TestAssembly.dll");
Assembly.LoadFile("TestAssembly.dll");
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
Assembly assembly = domain.Load(rawAssembly);
```

The initializer is called after

```
var t = Type.GetType("TestAssembly.Class1, TestAssembly", AssemblyResolver, TypeResolver, false, true);
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

i.e. on the first use of any type from assembly.
Is this normal behavior? Can I achieve a call to the initializer without any additional code on assembly loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/specs/Ecma-335-Augments.md#module-initializer)

> A module initializer is executed at, or sometime before, first access
> to any static field or first invocation of any method defined in the
> module.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want by calling `RunModuleConstructor` like this:

```cs
RuntimeHelpers.RunModuleConstructor( assembly.ManifestModule.ModuleHandle );
```